# Headers authorization not working after Cypress version update

Tags: automation, cypress, ui-automation

I am working on an automation project where I am using cypress. For a test user to log in, I am using:

```
Cypress.Commands.add("setAuth", () => {
    cy.intercept('https://url/privat', (req) => {
        req.headers['authorization'] = 'Bearer token'
    })
})
```

Cypress version I was using `6.9.1`. <-(Everything works fine on this version)

I am trying to update my Cypress version to `8.3.1` (latest)

After the update of cypress, the user is not getting logged in. I have no idea how to debug this or solve this.

Comment: Are you getting any error messages ?

Comment: No errors as such. All my requests to the backend (graphql) are going unauthorized - 401. Hence, it's not able to log in.

Answer (score 2):

ok, I solved it. In the older version cypress was able to intercept all calls done on `https://url/privat` so it was able to intercept calls for graphql too ex: `https://url/privat/graphql`

But in new version its not intercepting all calls. Now it needs to specify like `https://url/privat/**`

So, now it should be

```
Cypress.Commands.add("setAuth", () => {
    cy.intercept('https://url/privat/**', (req) => {
        req.headers['authorization'] = 'Bearer token'
    })
})
```

Works well now.